# Return rows with some text in them and delete the rest

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, drop

I have a dataframe df with values as below:

```
Common_words         count
0   realdonaldtrump  2932
2   new              2347
3                    2030
4   trump            2013
5   good             1553
6                    1440
7   great            200
```

I only need the rows where there is certain text. For e.g rows which have blank value like row 3 and row6 need to be removed.

```
Tried:

df = df.dropna(how='any',axis=0)
```

but still i get the same result. I feel these are not null values but spaces, so I also tried below:

```
df.Common_words = df.Common_words.str.replace(' ', '')
```

But still same result. Row 3 and 6 are still not removed. What to do?

Comment: `''` is not a null/nan either , replace with `np.nan`

Comment: Statement: `df.Common_words = df.Common_words.str.replace(' ', np.nan)` gives following error  `TypeError: repl must be a string or callable`

Comment: use `df.Common_words.replace` instead of str.replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df.Common_words =  df.Common_words.replace(r"\s+", np.NaN, regex=True)

df.dropna()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
df.replace(r'^\s+$', np.nan, regex=True)
df.dropna()
```